# "What many" VS "how many"

Tags: difference

> Even though Nikonov did not add **what many** already knew, … …

I saw the phrase in a book.  I'm wondering if there is any difference if we replace "what many" with "how many" here? Is there any difference in general between "how many" and "what many"?

Comment: 'How many' is a fixed phrase meaning 'what number', 'what many' is not; 'what' in your example means 'that which'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Here is something else, just an aside: Nik did not add how many already knew................in other words:  Nik did not mention how it was that a lot of people were already informed about etc.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. ***what many*** isn't meaningfully a "collocation" in the cited example. It's just two words that ***happen*** to occur consecutively, where conceptually and syntactically, ***what*** is equivalent to ***something which***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'How many' is a fixed phrase meaning 'what number', 'what many' is not a collocation; 'what' in your example means 'that which'.

> **how many**
>   PHRASE
>   used for asking or talking about the number of people, things etc that there are
>   *How many students are taking the test?*
>   *It’s surprising how many different varieties of pasta there are.*

[How Many (Longman Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/how-many)

> **what**
>   used when someone knows or says which thing, action, or idea
>   something is
>   *I told him what the problem was.*
>   *She wasn’t quite sure what she was going to say.*
>   *We suddenly realized what was happening.*

[What (Longman Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/what)